# How do I find the optimal position for a hydraulic damper to balance the force applied to a rotating assembly?

Tags: torque, mathematics

This may be a simple problem, my math and physics chops are a bit rusty.

I'm modifying a flight sim rudder pedal to add a hydraulic linear damper (specifically a motorcycle steering damper).  I'm trying to figure out how to mathematically find the optimal mounting position, and how to calculate the change in applied torque at different points in rotation.

The linear force of the damper should be consistent through travel; however, I know that as angle of the damper relative to the rotational position of the pedal assembly changes, the torque applied by the damper will also change.  I also am intuitively aware that the best/only way to perfectly balance the torque is to mount both ends of the damper radially from the center of rotation.  Unfortunately, this isn't an option.

I've roughly sketched the parameters below. Blue is the base, green the rotating pedal assembly, orange the damper (with blue damper rod), red is the area where the end of the damper rod can be mounted, linked to the base.  The sketch shows the damper above for visibility; it will be mounted below and on a plane with the rotating assembly.

If the sketch isn't quite clear, the item being modified can be found here:
https://virpil-controls.us.com/vpc-ace-collection-pedals.html

[image]

Comment: Why to only one pedal? What about two, mounted on the blue block to each arm?

Comment: Cost, primarily.  Each damper is $55 USD for the model I'm going with.

Comment: Then use rods and sleeves so you only need one damper. Also need cranks for the other direction.

Comment: I'm having a hard time picturing what you're suggesting.  What do you mean by rod/sleeve and crank?

Comment: Look at how hand controls work on cars.

Comment: Oh, you mean a rack and pinion.  That could work I suppose, although the additional cost of mfg/sourcing the appropriate parts would probably end up costing just as much as two dampers.  Mainly I'm trying to figure out the mathematics to calculate the torque curve of the system.

Comment: If I meant rack & pinion then those are the words I would have used.

Comment: K.  Thanks for the help, bud.